# Reference cells in sheet2 from sheet 1, but index the row with each drag down in sheet 1

Tags: excel, indexing

From sheet #1, I want to copy the value in sheet (Jim!).

This code works:
=IF(AND(Jim!B44=B14,Jim!C59>0),Jim!C59,0)

But, then when I drag the answer cell in Sheet #1 down 1 cell, I want the formula to reference the cell in C79, (59 + 20).

Then when I drag the answer cell in sheet #1 down 1 more cell, I want the formula to reference cell C99, (another 20 cell down in sheet Jim!.

How can I do this INDEXING?

Answer (score 0):

With INDEX():

```
=IF(AND(Jim!B44=B14,INDEX(Jim!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+59)>0),INDEX(Jim!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+59),0)
```

Comment: I have modified the first part of the "AND" for things in column B.

Comment: I have modified the first part of the "AND" for things in column B.  =IF(AND(INDEX(Jim!B:B,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+4)=B12,INDEX(Jim!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+19)<>0),INDEX(Jim!C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+19),0)    The final thing I need is to be able to also drag across to contiguous cells. The references to column "C" need and do change (D, E, F...) as I drag across, but the reference to column "B" needs to stay as "B".  Still allowing for the =Bxx part to increment as I drag down.